# How do I avoid compiler warnings when converting enum values to integer ones?

Tags: c++, boost, enums, integer

I created a class `CMyClass` whose CTor takes a `UCHAR` as argument. That argument can have the values of various enums (all guaranteed to fit into a `UCHAR`). I need to convert these values to `UCHAR` because of a library function demanding its parameter as that type.

I have to create a lot of those message objects and to save typing effort I use `boost::assign`:

```
std::vector<CMyClass> myObjects;
        boost::assign::push_back(myObjects)
            (MemberOfSomeEnum)
            (MemberOfSomeEnum);

std::vector<CMyClass> myOtherObjects;
        boost::assign::push_back(myObjects)
            (MemberOfAnotherEnum)
            (MemberOfAnotherEnum);
```

The above code calls the `CMessage` CTor with each of the two enum members and then puts them in a list.
My problem is, that this code throws the warning C4244 (possible loss of data during conversion from enum to UCHAR) on VC++9.

My current solution is to create a conversion function for each enum type:

```
static UCHAR ToUchar(const SomeEnum eType)
{
    return static_cast<UCHAR>(eType);
}

static UCHAR ToUchar(const AnotherEnum eType)
{
    return static_cast<UCHAR>(eType);
}
```

And then the above code looks like this:

```
std::vector<CMyClass> myObjects;
        boost::assign::push_back(myObjects)
            (ToUchar(MemberOfSomeEnum))
            (ToUchar(MemberOfSomeEnum));

std::vector<CMyClass> myOtherObjects;
        boost::assign::push_back(myObjects)
            (ToUchar(MemberOfAnotherEnum))
            (ToUchar(MemberOfAnotherEnum));
```

This is the cleanest approach I could think of so far.

Are there any better ways?
Maybe boost has something nice to offer?

I don't want to disable warnings with pragma statements and I cannot modify the enums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't be emabarrassed by static_cast here, but if you are:

```
template <class T>
inline UCHAR ToUchar(T t)
{
    return static_cast<UCHAR>(t);
}
```

saves writing a function for every enum.

Comment: That would result in having to write "ToUchar<SomEnum>(SomeEnumMember)" each time which would be less readable. That's what I meant with "clean".

Comment: No, the template argument is deduced:  ToUchar(SomeEnumMember)

Comment: Sorry, you're right! I should have tried it before writing the comment... :-/

Comment: The only downside to this neat solution is that it allows erroneous enums to be converted to UCHAR without compiler warnings.  The explicit constructors ensure that only the enums that intended for use will be used without warning.